# Strip char from array key

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm creating a Json object which has ids and each id has a subsequent position.
When processing this object as an array in PHP I need to keep the ids in the order they are genereated, however Chrome reorderes the ids in a numerical ascending order.

So as a work around I've added "id" to the ids in the object so chrome does not reorder it.
Now In php I have this array

```
Array
(
    [id102] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 1
        )

    [id95] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 2
        )

    [id101] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 3
        )

)
```

which will eventually go into a DB, but I need to remove the char "id" from the array keys.

The array is processed to ensure that the positions (['pos']) are sequential (which is why I needed to make sure they were in order)

```
$seqKey = key($values);

$seq = $values[$seqKey]['pos'];


foreach($values as $key=>$val){

    if($seq != $val['pos']){

       $values[$key]['pos'] = $seq;

    }

     $seq++;
 }
```

but any variation of ltrim($key, "id") or str_replace does not affect the main array once the loop is completed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the array at the top is the result of running the code at the bottom. It would be useful to show what the incoming data looked like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$new_arr = array();
array_walk($arr,function ($v,$k) use(&$new_arr) { $new_arr[str_replace('id','',$k)]=$v;});
print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/141876)</kbd>

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [102] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 1
        )

    [95] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 2
        )

    [101] => Array
        (
            [pos] => 3
        )

)
```

###Explanation :

Using `array_walk()` you can directly work with the keys and values of the original array that was subjected to it (*but I don't think you can modify the keys of it*) , so what I did was added a temporary array `$new_arr` before calling the `array_walk()`. Actually, we are going to pass the new modified keys and values to this `$new_arr` array. So inorder to use it, you make use of `use` keyword inside the function. Also `&` is for directly modifying the `$new_arr`. If you remove the `&`, then there will not be any changes done to it.

So basically, the original array `$arr` key is modified (`str_replace()`) and passed to `$new_arr` and the values passed to the `$new_arr`.

Comment: This worked perfectly.
Just so I understand what is happening here, would you be able to briefly explain what is happening in terms of array_walk and use(&newValues)? I find gettings something working is one thing, undetsanding it is another. If not, no worries and thankyou for your help!

Comment: @Shamrockonov, Added an explanation, if you still find it hard ask me, but before that go through the documentation of `array_walk()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
  $newArray[ltrim($key, 'id')] = $val;
}

uasort($newArray, function($a, $b){
  return $a['pos'] < $b['pos'] ? -1 : 1;
});
print_r($newArray);
```